# Help on unclear question determining a probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

The exercise of my homework assignment says

"Let $E$, $F$, $G$ be independent events with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{1}{5}$. Let $X$ be the number of events that occur. Determine the random variable $X$, its mean value and variance."

My concern is on the first question, and I hope to be able to explain it. Shouldn't I know how many of the event that occur belong to $E$, $F$, $G$? On a first guess I expect not to be able to write analitically $\Bbb{P}(X=k)$. My only attempt is by using conditioning, but I guess I should know how many of the three events occurred; defining $X\colon = X_1+\cdots+X_n$

\begin{multline}
\Bbb{P}(X = k) = \Bbb{P}(X=k|X_1,\cdots,X_{n_1}\in E)\cdot\Bbb{P}(X_1,\cdots,X_{n_1}\in E) + \\
\Bbb{P}(X=k|X_{n_1+1},\cdots,X_{n_2}\in F)\cdot\Bbb{P}(X_1,\cdots,X_{n_2}\in F) + \\
\Bbb{P}(X=k|X_{n_2+1},\cdots,X_{n_3}\in G)\cdot\Bbb{P}(X_1,\cdots,X_{n_3}\in G) + \\
\Bbb{P}(X=k|X_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3},\cdots,X_{n}\notin E\cup F\cup G)\cdot\Bbb{P}(X_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3},\cdots,X_{n}\notin E\cup F\cup G)
\end{multline}

where $n_1,\,n_2,\,n_3\,$ are the respective numbers of the events occurring that belong to $E$, $F$, $G$ respectively.

Let me know if my question is as unclear as the exercise is to me.

Comment: the question is far to be clear. The mechanic of the events "occurring" what is?

Comment: To answer your abstract question:  other possible events are irrelevant.  the question clearly refers to the number of the events $E,F,G$ that occur.  We can compute $P(X=3)$ for example as the product $\frac 12\times \frac 14\times \frac 15$.  Similarly $P(X=0)=\frac 12\times \frac 34\times \frac 45$.  The other cases are somewhat more tedious.